# Django меню не отображается!

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, views

Сначала написал такой код: views.py, меню работает.

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import datetime

def menu():
    data = [
        {'url': '/', 'description': 'Главная страница'},
        {'url': '/riddle', 'description': 'Загадка'},
        {'url': '/answer', 'description': 'Ответ на загадку'}        
    ]
    context = {'data': data}
    return context


def index(request):    
    context = menu()    
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)


def riddle(request):   
    context = menu()    
    return render(request, 'riddle.html', context)


def answer(request):
    context = menu()
    return render(request, 'answer.html', context)
```

Потом решил добавить 'title' и переделал views.py, меню исчезло.

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import datetime

def menu():
    data = [
        {'url': '/', 'description': 'Главная страница'},
        {'url': '/riddle', 'description': 'Загадка'},
        {'url': '/answer', 'description': 'Ответ на загадку'},        
    ]
    context = {'data': data}
    return context


def index(request):

     context = {         
         'title': 'HOME',
         'menu': menu() 
     }

    context = menu()
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)


def riddle(request):
    context = {
        'title': 'RIDDLE',    
        'menu': menu()
    }
    return render(request, 'riddle.html', context)


def answer(request):
    context = {
        'title': 'ANSWER',    
        'menu': menu()
    }
    return render(request, 'answer.html', context)
```

Answer (score 1):

Форма контекста у вас поменялась

Раньше меню лежало в data, а сейчас в menu.data

Comment: Понял, спасибо. Раньше была функция, а потом data c menu т.е. menu.data.menu. Попробую переделать.